# How can I determine least common multiple for a given number and all numbers before it?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, arithmetic

The wikipedia article on [least common multiples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) only talks about determining the least common multiple between 2 numbers. I'm looking for an algorithm that will determine it for a set of numbers 1 .. x where x is any positive integer.

eg. if x is 3, the answer would be 6 (6/3, 6/2, 6/1 all positive integers), if x is 4 the answer would be 12 (12/4, 12/3, 12/2, 12/1). I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Check out http://oeis.org/A003418

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $p$ is a prime $\le n$, then

$$p^{\alpha} \le n \iff \frac{\log n}{\log p} \ge \alpha$$

Now if $\alpha$ is the largest power such that $p^{\alpha} \le n$, convince yourself that $p^{\alpha}$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,...,n)$. Using this, you can write down an explicit formula in terms of such primes and such powers.